# Javascript tooltip help and color change

Tags: javascript, tooltip, mouseover, outsystems

I am fairly new with Javascript. Now, what I need is that I have a link in  my projectXYZ which leads to another projectABC. I need to change the color of the link and show a tooltip dialog for the MouseOver event of the link.

I tried to change the color, but could not succeed with the tooltip. Is there a combined solution which fulfills these requirements ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my Outsystems application for MouseOver style property of the link I gave the value "background-color : red"

Comment: Could you please add some code that you have tried ? did you try jquery ? or any other library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is said to be sufficient to add a 'title' attribute in tour DIV's and it will show up as tooltip on mouse-hover.

But to make a basic tooltip with proper positioning, you can use the below. I have used it and it works !!

JS (will have two mwthods, showTip and hideTip) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showtip(e,message) {
var x=0;
var y=0;
var m;
var h;
if(!e)
var e=window.event;
if(e.pageX||e.pageY) { x=e.pageX;  y=e.pageY;  }
else if(e.clientX||e.clientY)
{ x=e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft;y=e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop;}
m=document.getElementById('myTooltip');
if((y>10)&&(y<450))
{  m.style.top=y-4+"px";  }
else{  m.style.top=y+4+"px";  }
var messageHeigth=(message.length/20)*10+25;
if((e.clientY+messageHeigth)>510)
{  m.style.top=y-messageHeigth+"px"; }
if(x<850) { m.style.left=x+20+"px";  }
else{  m.style.left=x-170+"px";  }
m.innerHTML=message;m.style.display="block";m.style.zIndex=203;
}

function hidetip(){
var m;
m=document.getElementById('myTooltip');m.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#myTooltip{padding: 5px; background-color: #FFF8DC;  border: 1px solid #DEB887; width:180px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #6b6b6b; display:none; position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
</style>
```

And the HTML (will have an extra DIV below the href to show tooltip):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="showtip(event, 'Sample tooltip text');"
onmouseout="hidetip();">Hover mouse to see tooltip text.</a>
<div id="myTooltip" ></div>
```

Hope it helps !!