# Change format of the title attribute in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I'm want to know if it's possible change the background color or color text of the "test", in the picture below:

[test](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3s0H0Mxbliw/UnAUW8XBxtI/AAAAAAAAAAo/Bv4UQNKAk-s/s128/fig1.jpg)

I tried use tooltips, but it's not working. I'm using a dynamic table, example:

```
td = tr.insertCell();
td.innerText = whatever;
td.title = whatever;
```

Using tooltip, just the first data it's recorded. So, I'm using the "title" attribute, it's working with the data, but I can't edit the title.

I tried change the CSS, without success.

Comment: try this. `td.setAttribute('title','whatever');`

Comment: did you googled for it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, imsiso. But I don't want change the TEXT, I want to change the STYLE of the title.

Answer (score 0):

check this this is a way of adding new tool tip.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600959/2226796

Here is a sample code.

HTML:

```
<div class="nToolTip" title="title 1">text1</div>
<table border="1" class="nToolTipContainer">
    <tr>
        <td title="sstt1">some text 1</td>
        <td title="sstt2">some text 2</td>
        <td title="sstt3">some text 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td title="sstt11">some text 11</td>
        <td title="sstt12">some text 12</td>
        <td title="sstt13">some text 13</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="myTooltip">w</div>
```

JS:

```
var tm='';
var ntm='';
var E;
/* , nToolTipContainer [title] */
    $('.nToolTip[title] , .nToolTipContainer [title]').mouseover(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var title=$this.attr('title');
        $this.data('title', title);
        // Using null here wouldn't work in IE, but empty string will work just fine.
        $this.attr('title', '');
        ntm=title;
        E=e;
        tm=setTimeout(function(){
            showtip(E,ntm);
        },1000);//time that you want to hold your mouse on titles to apear
    }).mouseout(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
        hidetip();
    });
function showtip(e,message) {
var x=0;
var y=0;
var m;
var h;
if(!e)
var e=window.event;
if(e.pageX||e.pageY) { x=e.pageX;  y=e.pageY;  }
else if(e.clientX||e.clientY)
{ x=e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft;y=e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop;}
m=document.getElementById('myTooltip');
if((y>10)&&(y<450))
{  m.style.top=y-4+"px";  }
else{  m.style.top=y+4+"px";  }
var messageHeigth=(message.length/20)*10+25;
if((e.clientY+messageHeigth)>510)
{  m.style.top=y-messageHeigth+"px"; }
if(x<850) { m.style.left=x+5+"px";  }
else{  m.style.left=x-170+"px";  }
m.innerHTML=message;m.style.display="block";m.style.zIndex=203;
}

function hidetip(){
var m;
m=document.getElementById('myTooltip');m.style.display="none";
}
```

CSS:

```
#myTooltip{
    position:absolute;
    color:red;
    background:yellow;
}
```

and here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/gvwgj/1/

Comment: Tooltips do not work in my table. I forget to read that has a FOR to instanciate data, so there are many different titles.

Comment: I tested this code in my script, without any modification. Just to test. The style of the title remains the same. The "w" change color, but not the title. I'm using classic ASP, maybe for this it's not working.

Comment: @PedroLembiJúnior - I don't understand what you mean.did you tested the jsfiddle? My code works for tags that have `nToolTip` class or tags that their parent has class `nToolTipContainer` and deletes the titles attributes of them and fill the div `#MyToolTip` with their title value and then restores the title.

Comment: @PedroLembiJúnior - what you mean than "I tested this code in my script, without any modification"? please give the codes of how you have tested that?

Comment: The same code in jsfiddle. I just reproduced the same code in my script. Without any modification. The "w" in the last div acquires the value of CSS parameters (red and yellow), but the tittles don't.

Comment: @PedroLembiJúnior - are you there? lets go on chat

Comment: @PedroLembiJúnior - here is room link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/40532/tmp-for-solving-questions-19668010?tab=general. I'm waiting.

Comment: I give it up. It's impossible these titles change.